# How can I add and display aggerate sql functions in tkinter?

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter, aggregate-functions

#### I want to make a aggerate sql function that is presented in tkinter

I have a table for [products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlsIb.png) which I want to use to present AVG of the total prices using aggerate sql functions.

What I have done so far:

```
    Button(self.root,
           text="Average",
           command=self.avgprice).place(x=750,y=470,width=250,height=28)
```

This is the function which holds the aggerate sql:

```
        def avgprice(self):
            with sqlite3.connect("Stock_Control.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT AVG(Total) FROM Product")
                stock = cursor.fetchall()
                totalstock = 0
                messagebox.showinfo("Average Price",self.avgprice,parent=self.root)
                for stock in stock:
                    totalstock += stock[0]

                return totalstock
```

I am getting this error:

[The pop up doesn't pop up with the average price but this random numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v910N.png)

I think it might be a quick issue to fix but I am not to sure.

Comment: is `avgprice` a method on a class?  You're calling that way.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes avgprice is a method in the class and i'm trying to call it that way. I forgot to add (self).

Comment: @BryanOakley random numbers are being shown when I press the average button

Comment: you try to display `self.avgprice` which is reference to function `def avgpric(self)` - but you want to see `totalstock/len(stock)`

Comment: you use the same name `stock` in two places `for stock in stock` and it can be wrong idea

Answer (score 0):

You display `self.avgprice` which is reference to function `def avgpric(self)`
but you need `totalstock` - and you have to do after `for`-loop.

```py
    totalstock = 0

    for stock in stock:
        totalstock += stock[0]

    messagebox.showinfo("Average Price", totalstock, parent=self.root)
```

`Button` can't get result from function so `return totalstock` is useless.

---

But I would write it simpler (if I fetch result in correct way)

```py
def avgprice(self):
    with sqlite3.connect("Stock_Control.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT AVG(Total) FROM Product")
        
        average = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        messagebox.showinfo("Average Price", average, parent=self.root)
```